# Is there a way to skip every other input in a form for mobile devices?

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile

I have a simple basic form like:

```
<input type="text">
 <select>
  <option value="1">Opt1</option>
  <option value="2">Opt2</option>
 </select>
<br>
<input type="text">
 <select>
  <option value="1">Opt1</option>
  <option value="2">Opt2</option>
 </select>
```

The select box is a selection of units, which will be rarely used in the form completion process, but is necessary to be there.

My problem is that whenever you are on a touch device, touching on the next/prev buttons on the virtual keyboard, you have to pass through the select options as well.

Is there any way to bypass the select options while completing the form? The above example is the simplest form, but the form design-wise is very complex, so ideas like put them in another element and split them is out of the question.

I wonder what you guys can come up with!

Comment: You can also consider simply having the items hidden in mobile view.

Comment: items are needed also in mobile view. Let me check this tabindex thingie

Comment: This is just awesome. Although you know so much, you just keep learning... Is there any way to avoid going to these forms completely when you are out of input fields? Meaning, since they are not required fields to skip them in all?

Comment: Got it! You just leave the non-required fields out of tabindex! How cool is this? :) Thanks Mr. Alien! Saved me from an awfully big headache!

Comment: ...actually to skip them in all, you just use tabindex="-1"

Answer (score -1):

As mike brant said in the comment, you could use the media query in css to just hide the element and it will not be required any more, but also it will be as if they never existed.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  select {
  display:none;
  }
}
```

Comment: As I said, it's not required, but this doesn't mean it's not necessary to exist.

Comment: well that's what I interpreted 'fields to skip them in all' to be. And thank you very much for the down vote.